# Read a page stylesheet and check a specific property with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, css, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

What I am trying to do is:

1. Load the page
2. Gain access to the contents of an external css named "mystyle.css"
3. Check if ".some_class" border has the value "2px"

I have tried

```js
describe('CSS tests', () => {
    it('.some_class border is 2px', async function () {
        await page.goto(<homepageurl>);
        const stylesheet = await page.evaluate(() => {
            return document.querySelector("link[href*='mystyle.css']");
        });
        console.log(current_styles);
        // rest of the code
    });
});
```

I am getting an empty object {} as a result so I am lost and don't know how to carry on.

Comment: `querySelector('link')` returns a link Element, not the actual contents of the CSS URL.  Try inspecting and searching within `document.styleSheets` object. Also see [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

Comment: As an aside, `evaluate` can only return serialized JSON, not a DOM tree. `evaluateHandle` would make more sense, if getting a node is what you want to do (but it won't have any style info, it's just a link and you already know where the link points, so you might as well request `mystyle.css` directly, then parse it and check your property as described above).